# Stored Procedure refuses to delete column that it creates

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I've created a Stored Procedure that refreshes the data in a table. It first re-loads the entire table. Next, several filters are applied. (Example: the column 'Model' must equal 'W'; all rows with model 'B' are deleted.) This happens after the table has been loaded (and not during) because I want to log how many rows are deleted because of each individual filter. After the filters have been applied, some columns contain the same value in every row (the other values were deleted in the filtering process). These columns are now useless, so I want to delete them.

This seems to be problematic for SQL Server. When given the command to execute the SP, it indicates that the columns it is supposed to remove in its final step do not currently exist and refuses to run. That is technically correct, the columns currently don't exist, but they will be created by the SP itself.

Some mockup code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Procedure AS (
  DROP TABLE dbo.Table
  SELECT * INTO dbo.Table FROM dbo.View
  INSERT INTO dbo.Log VALUES (GETDATE(),(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Table))
  DELETE FROM dbo.Table WHERE Model <> 'W'
  INSERT INTO dbo.Log VALUES (GETDATE(),(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.Table))
  ALTER TABLE dbo.Table DROP COLUMN Model
)
```

Error code when executing:

```
[2016-09-02 12:25:20] [S0001][207] Invalid column name 'Model'.
```

How do I circumvent this problem and get the SP to run?

Comment: The reason for the error is that because `dbo.Table` exists, but without the `Model' column, when the proc is compiled.  The `ALTER TABLE` statement is validated against the schema without the column and fails.  Wrapping the alter statement in dynamic SQL will avoid the problem because the statement will then be compiled separately, immediately before execution.

Comment: @A. Stam : modify your script with correct syntax ' ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ***DELETE*** COLUMN Model' to  ALTER TABLE dbo.Table ***DROP*** COLUMN Model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can use dynamic SQL:

```
exec sp_executesql 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Table DROP COLUMN Model';
```

Comment: This compiles without errors. I'm testing the procedure now to check the result.

Comment: The procedure runs fine now. However, I had to format the query as follows: `DECLARE @sql nvarchar(100) = 'ALTER TABLE dbo.Table DROP COLUMN Model' ; EXEC sp_executesql @sql`. For some reason, sp_executesql wouldn't simply accept the string as an argument like in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax to remove any column from table in **SQL Server** is

```
ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName ;
```

This may be cause for issue.

Comment: That was a typo in the question, thanks for noticing. My syntax is correct in the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check one more time for the existency of the column 'Model' exists in the view.

because i have tried with the same scenario and its works for me..

[image]

Comment: The column 'Model' exists in the view. If you run your script again, does it still work? The first time the script is run it should be fine, because you might not have deleted the columns from the table already.

Comment: @ A. Stam : every time the table is getting dropped and recreated right??  it is not mentioned that VIEW has dependency with the Table. so there wont be any issue..